# Getting JButton To Work

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

right now I have some buttons on a calculator and they are not setup. I am confused as to how to get them to print something in the JTextField when clicked. I am aware that you need to  use ActionListener, but I cannot seem to get it working. Thanks for your help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private JTextField tf = null;
private JButton[] arrBtn = null;
private String[] btnNames = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "CE", "-", "+", "/", "%", "*", "=" };
private JPanel jp = new JPanel();
private char op = ' ';
private int num1 = 0;
private int num2 = 0;
private int result = 0;
private boolean isOpPressed = false;
private JPanel btnPl;

public Calculator() {
    super();

    jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    btnPl = new JPanel();
    btnPl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

    jp.add(new JTextField());
    jp.add(new JTextField());
    jp.add(new JTextField());
    jp.add(new JTextField());
    jp.add(new JTextField());
    jp.add(new JTextField());

    arrBtn = new JButton[btnNames.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrBtn.length; i++) {
        arrBtn[i] = new JButton(btnNames[i]);
        arrBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
        btnPl.add(arrBtn[i]);
    }

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(jp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(btnPl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Calculator();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    RomanCalculator cal = new RomanCalculator();
    frame.add(cal);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: Start with [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). You can use `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` to get the text of the button

Comment: *"..but I cannot seem to get it working."* Well `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}` where is this attempt to get them working? What is your question? At the moment the question seems to be 'Can you finish my program?' and although we can, we won't.

Comment: Nobody asked you to finish anything. I'm learning man. I don't know where to put those things that's why I asked. But, thanks for being an ass though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest first taking a looking at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html), and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Here is how you should be creating a new TextField

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
```

You should then create a button and action listener similar to this

```
JButton someBtn = new JButton("Some Text");
someBtn.addActionListener(this);
```

Your ActionPerformed

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    textField.setText("New Text");
}
```

If you would like to stay with the approach of using an Array of `JButtons` I suggest doing something similar.

```
String[] btnNames = {"1", "2", "3", etc.};
JButton[] allBtns = new JButton[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    allBtns[i] = new JButton(btnNames[i]);
    allBtns[i].addActionListener(this);
    //Using the previous actionPerformed
}
```

If you would like to customize what each button does you can do this

```
anyBtn.addActionListener(e -> textField.setText("Anything"));
```

Take a look at [lambda's](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) for more info.

Comment: Okay, that top bit makes everything so much easier because it was getting confusing as to which box stuff would be put in. Do you have any idea on how to put text over top of the box that disappears when a button is clicked. For example, in the top left box it would say "Num1" and once you click it that "Num1" disappears?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to set the text in the textfield to nothing? Or would you like something completely different such as a [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) to display "Num1"?

Comment: Possibly a JLablel. I'd like each of my six boxes to say something different. So like box one could say "Num1" and box two could say "Num2". But once a box is clicked, that "Num1" text is replaced by the button that is pressed. For example, if someone pressed a 1 for their first button. "Num1" would be replaced by a 1

Comment: I like hard coding the buttons, makes it a lot easier for me to see whats going on.

Comment: Take a look at the Lambda's link for info on that. :)

Answer (score 0):

the way I usually go about it in java is to have an inner class that handles the button clicks

```
public x extends JFrame(){
//I like to store my buttons in an array if possible. 
JButton [] buttonArray =  new JButton [2];

//instantialize each of the arrays buttons
buttonArray[0] = new JButton("hello");
buttonArray[1] = new JButton("world");

//create a listener of type buttonpress (currently undefined)
buttonPress Listener = new buttonPress();

//attach the button action listeners to the listener I created above.
buttonArray[0].addActionListener(Listener);
buttonArray[1].addActionListener(Listener);

//Create a private inner class called "buttonPress" which will handle the clicks for its listeners
private class buttonPress implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == buttonArray[0]){
            try
            {
                ..some logic                
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else if( e.getSource() == buttonArray[1])
        { 
            ...some other logic     
        }
    }

}//close inner class
}//close outer class
```